# What might be causing apparent nuget package self-references?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

I have a project file targeting `net 472`.  It depends on a bunch of libraries that are built against `netstandard2`.  Some of those libraries depend upon the **Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives** library although (as far as I can tell) there is no directly dependency from the root project.  When I build it, I see this warning...

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" and "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60".
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" was not.


    References which depend on "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll].
        C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll".
            C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll

    References which depend on "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" [].
        C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\lazycache\2.1.3\lib\netstandard2.0\LazyCache.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\lazycache\2.1.3\lib\netstandard2.0\LazyCache.dll".
            C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\lazycache\2.1.3\lib\netstandard2.0\LazyCache.dll
            D:\work\code\b6\Backend\CSharp\Libraries\Standard\TableAccess_std\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\TableAccess_std.dll
            D:\work\code\b6\Backend\CSharp\Libraries\Standard\CommsCode_std\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\CommsCode_std.dll
            D:\work\code\b6\Backend\CSharp\Libraries\Standard\Recognisers\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\Recognisers.dll
```

The relevant section, elided for readability, is

```
References which depend on "Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=5.0.0.0,... 
C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll

Project file item includes which caused reference...
C:\Users\neilm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\5.0.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
```

which seems to be describing a self-reference.  Any idea how this might be occurring? I've tried nuking the package cache, as well as the bin and obj folders but can't seem to get rid of it.  TIA.

*Edit* I should probably add this is just one of a number of **System** packages for which I am getting this warning.  Others include:

- System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsSource
- System.Memory.Data

*Edit 2* In case it is relevant, the root project is an Azure Cloud Service "Classic" worker role built using the Azure SDK which is why (regrettably) I can't just target .Net5 to try and work around this.

*Edit 3* The conflicts appear to be resolved when adding local dependencies at a matching version but I would still like to understand where the original conflict is coming from and what the warning is trying to tell me.  I *think* it is implying that the 472 framework depends on a different version of those packages/dlls but if so it's unclear what the appropriate resolution should be.

Comment: I struggle with exactly the same problem. Framework 4.7.2 app with dependencies on some Net Standard 2.0 projects.